# Spark: Difference between: sqlContext.read.load(path= '', format= '') and sqlContext.read.format().load()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to read a unicode delimited txt file on Spark2.2.
Initially was using the previous version of spark.read.load():

```
df= sqlContext.read.load(path='file:\\C:\Users\zr20684\Downloads\\SPEC_CUST_20190212230550.txt',
                         format= "com.databricks.spark.csv",
                         option= {"delimiter", "←"})
```

The entire row value was in a single column using above code.

```
[Row(_c0=u'01\u2190SPEC\u2190ZS\u2190SDN\u2190Insert\u219002/12/2019\u2190\u2190\u2190\u2190HCP\u2190CUST9635663\u2190\u2190\u2190JAMES\u2190\u2190DEANGELO\u2190\u2190\u2190\u2190\u2190\u2190\u2190\u2190JAMES DEANGELO\u2190\u2190\u2190\u2190\u2190\u2190A')]
```

While using below updated code:

```
df= sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "←").option("encoding", "UTF-8").load('file:\\C:\Users\zr20684\Downloads\\SPEC_CUST_20190212230550.txt')
```

It generated the result perfectly.

```
[Row(_c0=u'01', _c1=u'SPEC', _c2=u'ZS', _c3=u'SDN', _c4=u'Insert', _c5=u'02/12/2019', _c6=None, _c7=None, _c8=None, _c9=u'HCP', _c10=u'CUST9635663', _c11=None, _c12=None, _c13=u'JAMES', _c14=None, _c15=u'DEANGELO', _c16=None, _c17=None, _c18=None, _c19=None, _c20=None, _c21=None, _c22=None, _c23=u'JAMES DEANGELO', _c24=None, _c25=None, _c26=None, _c27=None, _c28=None, _c29=u'A')]
```

If I updated all my depricated code, will there be any scenario where my entire code will break?
I am assuming the updated one is a superset of the previous version.

Comment: Could you please try this out
`df = spark.read.load("file:\\C:\Users\zr20684\Downloads\\SPEC_CUST_20190212230550.txt", format="csv", sep="←")`

Comment: I would assume they are the same. Here you added `option("encoding", "UTF-8")` in the updated code, what happens if you add that option in the first case?

Answer (score 0):

`load` method [doesn't have `option`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f82ed5e8e0d2081db9894ae0ca737eddc4b0c390/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py#L141) argument so it is simply ignored.

Instead [options](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/f82ed5e8e0d2081db9894ae0ca737eddc4b0c390/python/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py#L148) should be provided as individual keyword arguments, i.e.

```
sqlContext.read.load(path='...', format = "csv", delimiter = "←")
```